# Using ExcelWriter on an existing workbook while using conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter

I'd like to use ExcelWriter to create a worksheet every week on an existing workbook.
However i'm stuck between, either:

1. Using openpyxl - which allows me to create the worksheet as intended but without cells formatting (on a range of cells)
2. Creating a workbook using the native XlsxWriter but that will overwrite the existing workbook.

I tried to search a solution on SO before asking this question.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I've had success with openpyxl and conditional formatting.

Here's how you would apply a rule, eg. `'A1>100'` to a range, eg. `'A1:C9'`

```
def cndfmt_fill(ws, rule, drange, col=None, fcol=None):
    try:
        fmt = {}
        if col: fmt['fill'] = PatternFill(bgColor=col)
        if fcol: fmt['font'] = Font(color=fcol)
        dxf = DifferentialStyle(**fmt)
        r = Rule(type="expression", dxf=dxf, stopIfTrue=True)
        r.formula = [rule]
        ws.conditional_formatting.add(drange, r)
    except:
        print('An error occurred trying to conditionally format range with rule:')
        print(drange)
        print(rule)
```